# Python to rename files in a folder with matching name in CSV file

Tags: python, asp.net, csv, rename

I am trying to write a script which will rename a block of asp files to their correct name.

Currently I have a folder which has asp files in it which are just named as id1.asp, id2,asp and so on.

I have a CSV file which has the ids in it and a description for that ID.

```
id1, pen
id2, rubber
id3, paper
etc.
```

I am trying to work out how to rename the `id1.asp` to be `pen.asp`, `id2.asp` to `rubber.asp` and so on.

Thank you. This is what I have tried so far:

```
import csv
import os
import shutil

a_csv_file = open("skuconvert.csv", "r")
dict_reader = csv.DictReader(a_csv_file)
for row in a_csv_file:
        print (row)

ordered_dict_from_csv = list(dict_reader)[0]
dict_from_csv = dict(ordered_dict_from_csv)

print(dict_from_csv)
dirs = os.listdir('./')

path = ''
head_tail = os.path.split(path)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be helpful if you post some code and tell us where it is failing.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried several solutions I have found on here:


Here is one I tried: import os


for old, new in zip(df['sku_Old'], df['desc_New']):
    os.rename(old, new)



Here is another:


import os
import csv
import shutil
with open('skuconvert.csv','rt') as csvfile:
    timeReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    i = 0 
    for row in timeReader:
        if i > 0:
            start_loc = row[1]
            save_loc = row[0]
            shutil.copy('start_location/{}'.format(start_loc), 'save_location/{}'.format(save_loc))
        i+=1

Comment: Does your CSV file have a header row? Or is it just `id1,pen` etc

Comment: It doesn't right now but I can add one.  I have edited the above code with my latest edit which recursively looks through all lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html?highlight=glob%20glob#glob.glob) to find all of your ASP files in a folder. First load your CSV file in as a dictionary (this assumes there are two columns, the IDs and the names). If there are more columns or if there is a header this would need to be dealt with differently.

```
import glob
import csv 
import os 
import shutil 

with open("skuconvert.csv") as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    ids = dict(csv_input)

asp_files = glob.glob(r"f:\dropbox\python temp\*.asp")

for asp_file in asp_files:
    path, basename = os.path.split(asp_file)
    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(basename)
    
    if filename in ids:
        new_name = os.path.join(path, f'{ids[filename]}{ext}')
        print(f"Renaming: '{asp_file}' to '{new_name}'")
        
        try:
            shutil.move(asp_file, new_name)
        except:
            print(f"Unable to rename: {new_name}")
    else:
        print(f"ID unknown: {filename}")
```

Then for each ASP file that is found, split out the path and extension and determine if the ID is found in the CSV file. If it is, build the new filename and call [`shutil.move()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html?highlight=shutil%20move#shutil.move) to rename the file. If it is not, then print the unknown file.

Comment: This is so close.  It has processed 5 of the files and then errored with: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 803, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)

Comment: Is the file open somewhere in another application? You can add a `try` `except` block around the call to skip over problematic files. It could be the target file already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CVS Reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) to read the filenames and create a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) mapping of id to new file name.  Then you can use [os.listdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) with [os.path.splitext()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) and [shutil.move()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) to rename your files.

Comment: import csv
import os
import shutil  




  
a_csv_file = open("skuconvert.csv", "r")
dict_reader = csv.DictReader(a_csv_file)
  
ordered_dict_from_csv = list(dict_reader)[0]
dict_from_csv = dict(ordered_dict_from_csv)
  


print(dict_from_csv)
dirs = os.listdir('./')
  
path = ''
head_tail = os.path.split(path)

  
source = './'
destination = './'
  
Thanks for the pointers.  So far I have this.  I can read the csv into an array but struggling on the renaming.